# Trying to embed a table within a table

Tags: tables

I am trying to add a table inside another table as a subtable to denote part of.

**Tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{float} % Better figure and table placements
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \small
        \noindent\begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1.6cm} | p{11.9cm} |}\hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Program requirements} \\ \hline
            Type & Priority  & Requirement \\ \hline
            FR & MUST   & The system must present the user with a feed. \\ \hline
            FR & MUST   & The system must be user-friendly. \\ \hline
            & & \\[-1ex]
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
                \begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{12cm} |}\hline
                    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{User module requirements} \\
                    \hline
                    Type & Priority & Requirement \\ \hline
                    FR & MUST & First name property. \\ \hline 
                    FR & MUST & Last name property. \\ \hline
                    FR & MUST & Base class. \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
            } \\[10ex] 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Is it, that you don't want the vertical lines in the empty row? Remove `& & \\[-1ex]` or replace is by `\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}\\[-1ex]` to avoid the unwanted vertical lines between the columns. Or is it something different?

Comment: Don't you get overfull box warnings? Your table is too wide for the width.

Comment: BTW: Professional tables usually don't need vertical lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ensures the tables fit in the available width (assuming rules are 0.4pt in width). I've also included some comments regarding things you might want to change e.g. using professional styles for tabular rules which means no verticals and variation in the weights of horizontals. `booktabs` provides the classic explanation and implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} % Better figure and table placements
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]% H is NOT a good idea - if you don't want it to move from here, don't use a float
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% the group table will limit the effect - no need for another group  
  \centering
  \small
  %\noindent% not necessary with \centering
  % consider using sans serif, especially for column heads
  \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{ | p{1cm} | p{1.6cm} | X |}
    \hline % consider using professional tabular rules e.g. booktabs (but not with vertical lines!)
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Program requirements} \\ \hline
    Type & Priority  & Requirement \\ \hline
    FR & MUST   & The system must present the user with a feed. \\ \hline
    FR & MUST   & The system must be user-friendly. \\\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\[-1ex]
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-0.8pt}{ | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | X |}\hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{User module requirements} \\
        \hline
        Type & Priority & Requirement \\ \hline
        FR & MUST & First name property. \\ \hline 
        FR & MUST & Last name property. \\ \hline
        FR & MUST & Base class. \\
        \hline
      \end{tabularx}
    } \\[10ex] 
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular fitted within tabular fitted to available width]